# Different background color for each element using :lt(3) Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table and I want the first 3 `TD` to have a different background color. I figured I could use the `:lt() Selector` for this, but at this point I am only able to give the first 3 `TD` the same yellow background color.

[I have the following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6u4Yu/)

I use the following code:

```
<script>
$( "td:lt(3)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
</script>
```

But as mentioned above, I want al 3 `TD` to have different background colors. How can I give the first `TD` a yellow background, the second `TD` a blue background and the third `TD` a red background?

Thanks

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/6u4Yu/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since all given answers work for me, I've given all points and randomly selected one as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a simple

```
var tds = $("td");
tds.eq(0).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
tds.eq(1).css( "backgroundColor", "blue" );
tds.eq(2).css( "backgroundColor", "red" );
```

You can also use [`:eq()` as a selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) if you want to repeat the `td` selection (which you shouldn't, though).

Alternatively, this will do it:

```
$( "td:lt(3)" ).css( "backgroundColor", function(i) {
    return ["yellow", "blue", "red"][i];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since all given answers work for me, I've given all points and randomly selected one as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good case for :nth-child... and :first-child since you want only the top row.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8GUTp/2/

```
<script>
$( "tr:first-child td:nth-child(1)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
$( "tr:first-child td:nth-child(2)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "blue" );
$( "tr:first-child td:nth-child(3)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "red" );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since all given answers work for me, I've given all points and randomly selected one as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:nth-child` selector:

```
<script>
    $('td:lt(3):nth-child(1)').css('backgroundColor','yellow');
    $('td:lt(3):nth-child(2)').css('backgroundColor','blue');
    $('td:lt(3):nth-child(3)').css('backgroundColor','red');
</script>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/6u4Yu/3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since all given answers work for me, I've given all points and randomly selected one as the answer.